# Angular routing with JS or PNG as substrings in route on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, routes, web-config

I run an Angular website on an IIS.

I defined routes and use a webconfig - and nearly everything works fine:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PageMainComponent },
  { path: 'singlekey', component: PageSingleKeyComponent },
  { path: 'singlekey/:lizKey', component: PageSingleKeyComponent },      
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];
```

**web.config:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SPA" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(?!.*(.js|.css|.png|.jpg|.ico|.svg)).*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/"  appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I use a URL like:

https://domain/singlekey/DE1234

DE1234 is passed correctly as param lizKey to the page/component.

But if the last part of the route contains an PNG or JS, I get an 404 error from the IIS:

https://domain/singlekey/JS1234

Is this something I have to clarify in the web.config or is this something I have to configure in the routing of angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change .js to .js and change .css to .css?

Comment: What? Where is the difference?

Comment: @Konrad . is considered as any character and \. is just a dot in regex expression. You can test that in IIS "test pattern".

Comment: Top. Worked! with \ . css